# Change column with string of percent to float pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I've essentially got this:

```
,    pct_intl_student
2879      %
2880     9%
2881    NaN
2882     1%
2883    NaN
Name: pct_intl_student, Length: 2884, dtype: object
```

Would it be possible in some easy way to change all the strings with a percent sign in them to a decimal number? So basically this:

```
,    pct_intl_student
2979    0
2880    0.09
2881    NaN
2882    0.01
2883    NaN
Name: pct_intl_student, Length: 2884, dtype: object
```

I do need the NaN values to stay in place, they will be converted to the average percentage number afterwards. The thing also is that NaN values should all stay as NaN, and the rows with merely the string '%' needs to become 0.

I tried:

```
df['pct_intl_student'] = df['pct_intl_student'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
```

But this raises this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

So I'm kindof at a loss right now

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: There has to be some other error going on, your code works fine for me

Comment: From your error message, it probably means you have a value in that column that is simply `"%"`. After stripping out the `%`, you are left with an empty string, which causes a `ValueError` when trying to convert to `float`. It actually tried to tell you which value caused the error, but an empty string prints out as...well an empty string. Scott's answer will not cause an error, but it may introduce `NaN` values in places where you did not expect, so be careful.

Comment: That might be true, some values might be 0 and then it just makes it an empty string, is there some easy way around this?

Comment: Try using `errors='coerce'` with `pd.to_numeric` That way any invalid casts will be converted to `NaN`

Comment: But those datapoints  should come out as 0, because the string '%' signifies 0 percent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example that better describes your issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["9%", "10%", np.nan, '%']})
print(df)
#     a
#0   9%
#1  10%
#2  NaN
#3    %
```

You want the string `%` to turn into the value `0`.

One way is to change your code to use `str.replace` instead of `str.strip`. Here I will replace the `%`s with `.0`

```
df['a'].str.replace(r'%', r'.0').astype('float') / 100.0
#0    0.09
#1    0.10
#2     NaN
#3    0.00
#Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 7):

Update:

```
df['pct_intl_student'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['pct_intl_student'].str[:-1])
                            .div(100)
                            .mask(df['pct_intl_student'] == '%', 0))
```

Output:

```
      pct_intl_student
2879              0.00
2880              0.09
2881               NaN
2882              0.01
2883               NaN
```

Use:

```
df['pct_intl_student'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pct_intl_student'].str.strip('%')).div(100)
```

Or

```
df['pct_intl_student'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pct_intl_student'].str[:-1]).div(100)
```

Output:

```
2880    0.09
2881     NaN
2882    0.01
2883     NaN
Name: pct_intl_student, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hmm that actually didn't work. It doesn't change anything. It might be because some of my datapoints are simply the string '%' because the value was 0 percent there. Is there some easy way around this?

Comment: You have to reassign it back to the dataframe column.

Comment: @chrisz also with fillna(0) : -)

Comment: @PEREZje Update the question with questioned/errant data.  Thanks.

Comment: V minor point, you can use `str.rstrip` instead of `str.strip`.